# Screen freezing in 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, delete, input-devices

So, unlike many others who have complained about everything freezing, I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 even before the LTS release and I used to love it as a matter of fact. Whenever I use it nowadays, if I try to delete some file or folder which is slightly above the ideal size of a file, probably a few MBs to a few GBs, first my touchpad hangs up, then my keyboard and my mouse, and I almost always have to force shut down my laptop.

Is there any remedy for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem which I faced too. It is because of the programs which are creating the problem. If you have any programs which you frequently use and when it is open the ubuntu freezes most of time then reinstall or uninstall it. If this doesn't fix your problem then scan and repair any corrupted or damaged files with the help of a 3rd party software. And at the end if this too doesn't fix it then backup your files and reinstall ubuntu.